# How to list all the KEYS packed in a bundle?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I tried the below code, but still i did not find the method that lists all the contained keys in a bundle.

JavaCode:

```
private void unpackBundle() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Set <String> mBundleKeysSet = this.mBundle.keySet();
    int size = mBundleKeysSet.size();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), size+" keys",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if ( mBundleKeysSet.iterator().hasNext() ) {
        //here i should display a list of the contained keys
                    //in the bundle
    }
}
```

Comment: you are just moving to the next key without doing anything. what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found the answer:

```
private void unpackBundle() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Set <String> mBundleKeysSet = this.mBundle.keySet();
int size = mBundleKeysSet.size();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), size+" keys",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mBundleKeysSet.toString() 
               ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

}